# RxJS calling second operation when first is successful

Tags: rxjs, observable, chaining

I'm using Angular2 and rxjs.

I have an operation called login(). This will use a http.post request to send the authentication details to the server and will then receive a token back.

It needs to read the result and if the token is received successfully it will do some operations to validate the token and decode it, and if all of this is OK then it will send the username from the token to the server with a http.get and retrieve the user's details.

I would like all of the above to be returned as one Observable, but I'm scratching my head as to how two operations that should occur one after the other should be structured using the RxJS way.

I don't think subscribing to the first operation and then calling the second operation inside the first is the "right" way, because then how do you capture a failure in the first one.

Something like this?

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/auth/token', creds, {
    headers: headers
})
.map(res => res.json())
.do(
    // validate token
    // decode token
)
.thenDo(
    // get user details
    this.http.get(url, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .do(
         //save user and token in localStorage
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about Rxjs `do and thenDo` function but yes you can do like this

```
 this.http.post('http://localhost/auth/token', creds, {
        headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => {
        return [{status: res.status , json: res.json()}]
        })
    .subscribe(res=>{
        if(res[0].status == 200){   // do you action depends on status code you got assuming 200 for OK response
            this.validateToken()  // Validate your token here in some  method named as validateToken
            this.decodeToken()  // decode token here in this method
            this.getUserDetail() //if everything worked fine call your another get request in another method 
        }
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err, err.status)    //catch your error here 
        })

        getUserDetail(){
            // make http get request for user detail and saveing into locastroage
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flatMap` is a good way to chain operations that each return a new Promise or Observable. Each time we need to map over a function that returns a Promise or Observable, we can use `flatMap` to construct a stream that emits the resolved data. Here we construct an Observable of user data, and finally we can subscribe to it (to save to localstorage, etc).

I've assumed your validation code is just some function that returns a Promise or Observable.

```
const options = { headers };
const user$ = this.http.post('http://localhost/auth/token', creds, options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .flatMap(validationFunctionThatReturnsAPromise)
  .flatMap(authResponse => {
    // get user details
    return this.http.get(url, options).map(res => res.json());
  });

user$.subscribe(user => /** do something with the user data **/);
```